# VB.NET unable to differentiate between overloaded functions

Tags: vb.net, mvvm, overloading, mvvm-light

Current version of MVVM Light has a helper function named `Set` in `ObservableObject` class that an inheriting ViewModel class can call to both change property value and raise change notification in one call. Together with the new `NameOf` operator, this makes the boilerplate code of properties much smaller.

The problem however is that the `Set` function is overloaded and out of the 3 overloads, the following 2 overloads make VB.NET angry:

```
Protected Function [Set](Of T)(propertyName As String, ByRef field As T, newValue As T) As Boolean
Protected Function [Set](Of T)(ByRef field As T, newValue As T, <CallerMemberName> Optional propertyName As String = Nothing) As Boolean
```

Now if you have a `String` type property, VB.NET cannot differentiate as to which overload we are calling.

> Overload resolution failed because no accessible '[Set]' is most specific for these arguments:
>
> 'Protected Overloads Function [Set](Of String)(propertyName As String, ByRef field As String, newValue As String) As Boolean': Not most specific.
>
> 'Protected Overloads Function [Set](Of String)(ByRef field As String, newValue As String, [propertyName As String = Nothing]) As Boolean': Not most specific.

Note that C# can handle this situation easily, by using `ref` keyword. Also that even though the current situation is related to MVVM Light, the problem itself is generic. I have tried to use named parameters too, but that doesn't help either. Any hints on how this could be solved?

Comment: A workaround could be to create your own structure where you override the operators to match against a private `String` field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here again after almost a year. I just found a little workaround that would work in most cases. Instead of calling one of the overloads mentioned in the question, use the third overload:

```
Protected Function [Set](Of T)(ByRef field As T, newValue As T, <CallerMemberName> Optional propertyName As String = Nothing) As Boolean
```

The third parameter of this overload is optional and if you skip it in the call, it will use `CallerMemberName` to assign it a value. Since `Set` is almost always called from within the property, this approach should work nicely. No other overload takes two parameters, so compiler can resolve it correctly.